# Android gradle custom resources

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-resources

Is it possible to somehow make your own resource file so that you can receive data by analogy with strings (R.custom.field1), and at the same time all the same rules are observed as for other resources. Now I usually use xml, repack and usually. And I don’t want to stuff it into R.string, since these data are different, although they look the same.

Comment: hmmm. This seems a unique topic. But, AFAIK, it is not possible

Comment: @Sambhav.K I hope it's not)

Comment: What do you want in custom ?

Comment: There is a set of string data that is not formed by a programmer, and they can be the same as in R.string. To avoid mistakes, I took them out separately. But working with xml is not very convenient.